# Vue.js BreadCrumbs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently my **BreadCrumbs** in **vue.js 2.0** look like this:

```
<template>
    <ol class="Breadcrumb">
        <li class="Breadcrumb-item">
            <router-link class="Breadcrumb__link" :to="{ name: 'forum' }">
                Forum
            </router-link>
        </li>

        <li class="Breadcrumb-item" v-for="item in this.$route.params">
            <router-link class="Breadcrumb__link" :to="{ name: 'forum' }">
                {{ item }}
            </router-link>
        </li>
    </ol>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    }
</script>
```

[image]

But currently everything links to `/`. Is there a way how I could fix this? So every breadcrumb links to the right place.

It's difficult I guess because every route needs different parameters.

Comment: Well, you set every route to link to `name: 'forum'`.

Comment: Yes I know. But I would like to link every breadcrumb to the right place.

Comment: I'm new to vue.js, but I assume that you would have to set something like `name: item` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to check at which position you're at in the `$route.params` and then take all previous entries glued together with `/`. Can you provide more info of what's in your routes file or provide a jsfiddle?

As pointed out by Cristy, now your routes all point to the named route `forum`